# Amchart doesn't show up when listed with html <select> tag

Tags: amcharts

My previous issue was to get json data attached to amcharts, after struggling for a while, I got it running the way I want. But when I move it from test page to page where it would be listed with other charts it doesn't seem to work. When I click on blank chart this error appears in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.xToIndex (serial.js:14)
    at b.handleCursorMove (serial.js:8)
    at Object.a.inherits.b.fire (amcharts.js:1)
    at Object.dispatchMovedEvent (amcharts.js:27)
    at Object.handleMouseDown (amcharts.js:26)
    at b.handleMouseDown (serial.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (amcharts.js:18)
```

Below is the code which is working when I have it on separate page

```
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart1", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "#myURL"
    },
    "valueAxes": [{
      "title": "Load Average",
      "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "gridAlpha": 0.2,
      "dashLength": 0
    }],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
            "id": "AmGraph-1",
            "lineThickness": 3,
      "valueField": "LoadAverage"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
      "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
      "cursorAlpha": 0,
      "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "EndTimeLoop",
    "categoryAxis": {
      "title": "End Time Loop",
      "gridPosition": "start",
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      "tickPosition": "start",
      "tickLength": 20,
      "labelRotation": 90
    }
  });

  function setDataSet(dataset_url) {
    AmCharts.loadFile(dataset_url, {}, function(data) {
      chart.dataProvider = AmCharts.parseJSON(data);
      chart.validateData();
    });
  };
```

this is the part where select happens in html side

```
<div class="chartWrapper" id="chartSingleTest1">
              <select onchange="showChart(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                  <option value="chart1">Chart #1</option>
                  <option value="chart2">Chart #2</option>
                  <option value="chart3">Chart #3</option>

                </select>
              <div id="chart1" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;"></div>
              <div id="chart2" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;"></div>
              <div id="chart3" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
```

and here is js part where selects the first option on page load

```
var currentChart;
function showChart( divid ) {

  if (currentChart !== undefined)
    currentChart.style.display = "none";
  if ( divid ) {
    currentChart = document.getElementById(divid);
    currentChart.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    currentChart = undefined;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() { showChart('chart1'); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the chart object's `validateSize` method when toggling the display of a chart from `none` to `block` as shown in [this example that uses tabs](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/show-chart-hidden-tabs/). Here's another example using your structure:

```js
var charts = {};

charts["chart1"] = AmCharts.makeChart("chart1", {
  type: "serial",
  dataProvider: [{
    "value": 1,
    "category": "Category 1"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "category": "Category 2"
  }, {
    "value": 3,
    "category": "Category 3"
  }],
  categoryField: "category",
  graphs: [{
    valueField: "value",
    type: "column",
    fillAlphas: .8
  }]
});

charts["chart2"] = AmCharts.makeChart("chart2", {
  type: "pie",
  dataProvider: [{
    "value": 2,
    "title": "Slice 1"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "title": "Slice 2"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "category": "Slice 3"
  }],
  titleField: "title",
  valueField: "value"
});

var currentChart;

function showChart(divid) {

  if (currentChart !== undefined)
    currentChart.style.display = "none";
  if (divid) {
    currentChart = document.getElementById(divid);
    currentChart.style.display = "block";
    charts[divid].validateSize();
  } else {
    currentChart = undefined;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  showChart('chart1');
});
```

```css
.chartBoxSingle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<div class="chartWrapper" id="chartSingleTest1">
  <select onchange="showChart(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="chart1">Chart #1</option>
    <option value="chart2">Chart #2</option>
  </select>
  <div id="chart1" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="chart2" class="chartBoxSingle" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example works again on an external page but when I move it to my page even when I delete all charts and only use your example I get the same error :S

Comment: I fixed it somehow but can't really say how :D

Comment: quick question, If I want to show multiple values on one chart using json, how would I sort the "valueField" ?

Comment: If you you need to display multiple values, you need multiple graphs. Add another graph to the graphs array with a new valueField.